# Moodle having trouble with updating

Tags: moodle

I am running a moodle server and wanted to upgrade it to 3.11.8+, which resulted in the following installation errors:

[image: View here]

I already removed any external Plugins form the installation, so I guess the error is with either my database or moodle code directory. Not sure tho, since I am kind of new to the moodle administrating scene.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Text version

Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Invalid property requested, or the property does not has a default value.

More information about this error

Debug info: Error code: codingerror

```
Stack trace:
• line 929 of /lib/classes/user.php: coding_exception thrown
• line 300 of /user/editlib.php: call to core_user::get_property_default()
• line 150 of /user/editadvanced_form.php: call to useredit_shared_definition
• line 214 of /lib/formslib.php: call to user_editadvanced_form-> definition()
• line 155 of /user/editadvanced.php: call to moodleform->__construct()
```

Output buffer:

```
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$navcourselimit in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/navigationlib.php</b> on line <b>3051</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$maxbytes in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editadvanced.php</b> on line <b>123</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$maxbytes in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editadvanced.php</b> on line <b>145</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultcity in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>696</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$country in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>697</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$calendartype in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>701</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultpreference_mailformat in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>718</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultpreference_maildigest in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>20</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultpreference_maildisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>722</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultpreference_autosubscribe in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>724</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$defaultpreference_trackforums in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/lib/classes/user.php</b> on line <b>726</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>450</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>487</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>487</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>487</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass::$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>487</b>
<br /> 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: stdClass:$fullnamedisplay in <b>/var/www/html/moodle/user/editlib.php</b> on line <b>493</b>
<br />
```

Comment: Can you show navigationlib.php around line 3051?

Comment: Hope this is the right line: https://imgur.com/a/riQpmOt

Comment: The problematic line looks to be `$limit = (int) $CFG->navcourselimit`. Here it seems that `navcourselimit` was not properly initialized and therefore you get the notice you have mentioned.

Comment: For future reference - can you add the text rather than an image, it makes it easier to read and search

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the database hasn't been set up correctly

Can you check `config.php` for this line

```
$CFG->dbname    = 'yourdatabasename';
```

Is it the correct database?

Are there tables in the database?

Is it an empty database?

Comment: No, the database has everything it should have. It's not empty.